# Unity 2021.3.18f-Gradle Build failed : Protocol I NEED A HERO

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, gradle.properties

this is my first post about Unity, i'm migrating a project from Unity 2019.1.7 to Unity 2021.3.18f.
I could update most of the packages, I think unity did almost all updates, except the OculusIntegration, which I updated following this guide : [https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-import/#import-from-dev-center](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

However everything related to built the project using Gradle continues giving errors.I post what I had at the moment

---

**Using :**

- Unity 2021.3.18 f
- Custom Android Module (Android Build Support)
- OculusIntegration.unitypackage

---

**Errors **
1.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
47 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 42 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2. 

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\diego\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

3. 

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\diego\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

This is what I have

[First error window after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cLwe.png)

[gradle.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h14M.png)

[Built Settings > Player Settings > Player > Android > Publishig Settings > Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnJRM.png)

I have been searching how resolve this and I have found that these errors can be fix by modifying the gradle.properties, in fact I have commented the line `android.enableR8=false`due to a previous error, also I've been checking some boxes in Built Settings > Player Settings > Player > Android > Publishing Settings. I have attached some screenshots.

I have been fighting with Gradle for almost two weeks, I need your help guys.
May the force be with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering this question, I strongly suggest don't upgrade your project to another unity version. It's pretty dangerous because, during the upgrade process, there is a chance to lose some files that can cause your project to destroy.

Coming to the question, seems like you had added a key to your project which is in the project settings you can see in the image. delete the old key and create a new key  [Key store manager in project settings for android platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJrUB.png) Hope that works.

Comment: I think it's wrong to say don't upgrade a project to a higher version of Unity. Then it obviously depends on the needs of the developer and the longevity of the project. Of course you need to make a backup before each upgrade, and avoid downgrading projects.

Comment: you are right brother .